# Highcharts: How to shrink bubble radius on legend item hover?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

#### What I would like to accomplish:

I am trying to represent the bubble size (z value) in the legend. When that legend item is hovered over or toggled off the bubbles should shrink to equal sizes, like a normal scatter plot.

#### What I've tried so far:

I was able to get a legend item to represent the size by adding a new series with no data. I linked the 2 series that have data to this new one. I then overrode Highcharts legend hover function so that when the "size" legend item is hovered the linked series stay fully visible.

Like so:

```
series: [
  {
    type: "bubble",
    name: HotSpotResources.Positive,
    color: "#2699FB",
    data: points[0], //example data like -> {x: 10, y: 12, z: 150, id: "some_id"}
    linkedTo: "nsize",
    showInLegend: true
  },
  {
    type: "bubble",
    name: HotSpotResources.Negative,
    color: "#F8A6A6",
    data: points[1],
    linkedTo: "nsize",
    showInLegend: true
  },
  {
    id: "nsize",
    type: "bubble",
    name: HotSpotsResources.nSize,
    color: "#4A4A4A",
    marker: {
      symbol: `url(${LayoutResources.AppRoot}/assets/images/nsize-icon.svg)`
    },
  }
],
```

and the legend hover override:

```
(function (H) {
  H.Legend.prototype.setItemEvents = function (item, legendItem, useHTML) {
    const legend = this,
      boxWrapper = legend.chart.renderer.boxWrapper,
      activeClass = 'highcharts-legend-' + (item.series ? 'point' : 'series') + '-active',
      hasLinkedSeries = item.linkedSeries && item.linkedSeries.length ? true : false,
      setLinkedSeriesState = (item, state) => {
        item.linkedSeries.forEach((elem) => (elem.setState(state)));
      };

      // Set the events on the item group, or in case of useHTML, the item itself (#1249)
      (useHTML ? legendItem : item.legendGroup).on('mouseover', () => {
        if (item.visible) {
          item.setState('hover');
          // Add hover state to linked series
          if (hasLinkedSeries) {
            setLinkedSeriesState(item, 'hover');
          }
          // A CSS class to dim or hide other than the hovered series
          boxWrapper.addClass(activeClass);

          legendItem.css(legend.options.itemHoverStyle);
        }
      }).on('mouseout', () => {
        legendItem.css(H.merge(item.visible ? legend.itemStyle : legend.itemHiddenStyle));

        // A CSS class to dim or hide other than the hovered series
        boxWrapper.removeClass(activeClass);

        item.setState();
      }).on('click',(event) => {
        const strLegendItemClick = 'legendItemClick',
          fnLegendItemClick = () => {
            item.setVisible ? item.setVisible() : "";
          };

        // Pass over the click/touch event. #4.
        event = {
          browserEvent: event
        };

        // click the name or symbol
        if (item.firePointEvent) { // point
          item.firePointEvent(strLegendItemClick, event, fnLegendItemClick);
        } 
        else {
          H.fireEvent(item, strLegendItemClick, event, fnLegendItemClick);
        }
    });
  };
})(Highcharts)
```

So far so good.

I tried shrinking the size with just css but being an svg it was not possible / it produced ill results. Scaling them also changed their position so that was out of the question.

```
.highcharts-series-hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: transform 250ms;
}
```

I was able to shrink the bubbles on hover (of the bubble itself not the legend item) by changing marker state:

```
plotOptions: {
  bubble: {
    marker: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          radius: 4
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I want that same result when hovering the size legend item, not when hovering the bubble.

Finally, here's a screenshot of the chart I have created for reference:

[image: highcharts bubble example]

Can anyone find a way to manipulate Highcharts to accomplish this task or help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events in a wrap of `renderItem` method and change type of the series that are unhover to `scatter`.

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'renderItem', function(proceed, item) {
    proceed.call(this, item);

    var chart = this.chart,
      series = chart.series,
      element = item.legendGroup.element;

    element.onmouseover = function() {
      series.forEach(function(s) {
        if (s !== item) {
          s.update({
            type: 'scatter'
          }, false);
        }
      });

      chart.redraw();
    }
    element.onmouseout = function() {
      series.forEach(function(s) {
        if (s !== item) {
          s.update({
            type: 'bubble'
          }, false);
        }
      });

      chart.redraw();
    }
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r64f3w5n/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, instead of using the `update` then `redraw` approach I am looping over each point and setting it's state:  `point.setState("select");`. This allows the chart to animate, I'll check your answer though since it got me there.